# Full text search in Elasticsearch - what goes through the analysis?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-analyzers

From what I have heard, with a full text search query both the data stored in the text field **as well as** the query value goes through the analyzer. I am not sure what to mean by the fact that the query value also goes through the analysis.

In elasticsearch documentation I didn't find any information about it, for example - definition of default analyzer: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/analysis-standard-analyzer.html

Text analysis: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis.html

Full text queries: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html

In the documentation it says:

> Elasticsearch performs text analysis when indexing or searching text
> fields

So only the data in the text field is mentioned. So is it true that the query value also undergoes analysis? I can't find information if this is the case.

Comment: You missed this link which explains how it works: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-index-search-time.html

Comment: Thank you so much for the comment! It's all clear now. I must have missed it :D